# Raphaël mirroring images

Tags: svg, raphael, vml

I'm using Raphaël to create a build-your-own visualizer for a client. The code is working great in IE9 and younger, that is as SVG.  However, the client still has needs us to support IE8 which uses VML. Raphaël generates the VML for IE8, except it doesn't apply the **transform("s-1,1,0,0")**.  I know there are VML attributes that would take care of this but I can't seem to find how Raphaël may interact with them.

Is there anyway for me to get Raphaël to invert the generated VML shape?

Comment: Can you put a demo in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use small hack to create mirroring effect in Raphael.

Do this:

1. create you element: i.e. `var path1 = paper.path("your path");`
2. clone it into another path: `path2 = path1.clone();`
3. rotate('90') or 180
4. and finally, rearrange the `x` or `y` axis to get the mirror effect.

On top of this, you can even make you mirror to look faded by using `opacity property`. This is COOL!

Comment: I'm sorry, i wasn't completely clear about what i need.  I need it mirrored across the y-axis and I already have this working for the SVG. But for some reason the VML version doesn't recognize the transformation string "s-1,1".